# Authorization mechanism in Keycloak looking in DB for roles/permissions

Tags: java, authorization, keycloak

I need to implement authorization mechanism in Keycloak which looks into my customer's DB for user's permission based in roles.

I can't manage such roles and permissions in Keycloak's admin console but I will have to write some SPI to implement my authorization logic. Something like implementing a User Storage Provider to look in DB for user/password autentication.

But I can't find how to implement it. I think that, after obtaining a valid token for the user in authentication process, the application should send that token along with the permission needed to perform an action so Keycloak (my own SPI implementation) would validate the token and search the DB to grant permission.

Maybe the flow of authorization is different to what I think (what I wrote before).

Any clue would be appreciated.

How should the application send the token + permission to Keycloak?

How to implement a SPI which responds to such petition and validates the token?

Comment: What database are you using to store the users and roles? Do you have a way to deploy jars to the keycloak server?

Comment: @AbrahamCiokler It's an Oracle DB and yes, I have already deployed an User Storage Provider to Keycloak so I can authenticate users in the very same DB I refer to in my question. I think there must be some mechanism similar to User Storage Provider to do the authorization of resource acces based on DB queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question: Keycloak will handle the authorization flow for you, you don't need to worry about that part. All you need to do is to provide the User Storage SPI by implementing the methods of the `UserStorageProvider` interface.
Keycloak documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi

To also add the roles/permissions you need to implement the `UserModel` interface which has methods for handling roles/permissions. keycloak documentation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#model-interfaces

To combine these two, you would fetch the user record from the Oracle DB using the `UserStorageProvider` and fill in the `UserModel` fields (email, name, roles, etc..).

Ex pseudo code:

NOTE: look at keycloak documentation for a more detailed walkthrough: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#simple-read-only-lookup-example

```java
public class OracleDbUserStorageProvider implements UserStorageProvider, UserLookupProvider {

   private Map<String, UserModel> loadedUsers = new HashMap<>();

   private OracleDbRepository oracleDbRepository;

​   @Override
   ​public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
       ​UserModel user = loadedUsers.get(username);
       ​if (user == null) {
           ​OracleUser oracleUser = oracleDbRepository.getUser(username);
           ​if (oracleUser != null) {
               ​user = convertToUserModel(oracleUser);
               ​loadedUsers.put(username, user);
           ​}
       ​}
       ​return user;
   ​}

   private UserModel convertToUserModel(OracleUser oracleUser) {
        // take oracleUser attributes and assign to a UserModel instance
        return userModel; // user model converted
   }

}
```

Hope this helps set you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't see how this would work. Once the user returned by getUserByUsername(...) contains it's role/permission as attributes, Keycloak returns a JWT token which doesn't contains that information. How should the service ask to Keycloak if a user (identified by a token) has a permission?

Comment: Have you tried it? By your comment I'm assuming you already tried this approach and it didn't work. If that's the case, then there's always the approach of not sending the roles/permissions in the JWT token, but rather fetch them in your application when the user logs in. I have done this with spring in the past. The cons of this is that you would need to fetch the roles per request, but the pros is that the token will contain less information which makes it more secured and smaller footprint. Like everything, it's a trade off. Which technology stack do you use in your application?

Comment: I added role to my UserModel (getRoleMappings().add(...)) and it appears in the token. I guess that the correct way to proceed is that my web services server look for the correct role in the token and then validate the token (it's signed, it has not expired, etc) against Keycloak. I was trying to validate the roles/permission in Keycloak but I now think that this logic must be implementen in my server. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Your application is the one responsible for making sure the user has the appropriate role to access a certain resource like database record or page. Keycloak should only worry about logging in the user, retrieving its roles and keeping the user session.